# Passing data to AngularJS mddialog error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, mddialog

Im having some trouble with $mdDialog function for AngularJS material. The **prosess is like this:**
1) HTTP.get request to API and save the data into $scope
2) ng-repeat on view for table
3) User can click on a row and modal is shown (this is problem)
4) The data from row clicked will be shown in modal as title

**As you can see my AngularJS controller code:**

```
 $scope.showAdvanced = function(ev, variable_name) {
        console.log(variable_name);
        $mdDialog.show({
            locals:{dataToPass: variable_name},
            templateUrl: 'save-dialog.tmpl.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: ev,
            clickOutsideToClose:true,
            isolateScope: false,
            controller: DialogController

        })
            .then(function(answer) {
                $scope.status = 'You said the information was "' + answer + '".';
            }, function() {
                $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
            });
        function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {

            $scope.hide = function() {
                $mdDialog.hide();
            };

            $scope.cancel = function() {
                $mdDialog.cancel();
            };

            $scope.answer = function(answer) {
                $mdDialog.hide(answer);
            };
        }
    };
```

The error message i get in console is this(This happends ONLY when i add the line `controller: DialogController` inside `$mdDialog.show`, and im following the documentation right:

> Docs: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/dialog

`variable_name`  is just a variable that i get from the row clicked, if anyone have any better solution please tell. Purpose of the modal is to write some data inside modal and click submit that sends data to DB.

**This is the error message:**

```
main.min.js:3 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: tProvider <- t
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$injector/unpr?p0=tProvider%20%3C-%20t
    at main.min.js:2
    at main.min.js:2
    at Object.r [as get] (main.min.js:2)
    at main.min.js:2
    at r (main.min.js:2)
    at i (main.min.js:2)
    at Object.a [as invoke] (main.min.js:2)
    at c.instance (main.min.js:3)
    at o._createController (main.min.js:17)
    at Object.i [as link] (main.min.js:17)
```

Comment: Your controller seems to be undefined. You can do something like: `controller: function($scope){ }`

Comment: Should work fine. Make sure version of angular material is compatible with angular version used

Answer (score 0):

Using anonymous controller should solve your issue.

```
 $scope.showAdvanced = function(ev, variable_name) {
        console.log(variable_name);
        $mdDialog.show({
            locals:{dataToPass: variable_name},
            templateUrl: 'save-dialog.tmpl.html',
            parent: angular.element(document.body),
            targetEvent: ev,
            clickOutsideToClose:true,
            isolateScope: false,
            controller: function($scope, $mdDialog) {

              $scope.hide = function() {
                  $mdDialog.hide();
              };

              $scope.cancel = function() {
                  $mdDialog.cancel();
              };

              $scope.answer = function(answer) {
                  $mdDialog.hide(answer);
              };
          }
        }).then(function(answer) {
                $scope.status = 'You said the information was "' + answer + '".';
            }, function() {
                $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
        });
    };
```

Concerning your `dataToPass`, you need to inject it too.

```
function($scope, $mdDialog, dataToPass){
    console.log(dataToPass) // Working
}
```

Comment: im still getting this error: Unknown provider: tProvider <- t

Comment: This worked when i removed the injection in controller: function($scope, $mdDialog), but still i dont get the variable from: dataToPass. this is empty in modal even if the console.log shows right variable.

Comment: i think there is something else that is the problem. Still getting Unknown provider: eProvider <- e. Now it got from t to e

Comment: You didn't provide enough code for solving this issue. Please provide AngularJS version, Angular Material version, and how you load script that calls modal open

Comment: AngularJS v1.5.11, AngularJS Material v1.1.5

Answer (score 0):

the md-dialog expects an angular controller.

you have to register your controller function as real angular controller (it also probably make sense to have this outside of the showAdvance function scope)

So do sth like this

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('DialogController', DialogController);
```

and in your dialog configuration it needs to be a string so

```
$mdDialog.show({
    locals:{dataToPass: variable_name},
    templateUrl: 'save-dialog.tmpl.html',
    parent: angular.element(document.body),
    targetEvent: ev,
    clickOutsideToClose:true,
    isolateScope: false,
    controller: 'DialogController'
})
```